# The output of a fizbuzz function is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript code that is not running in the console in Chrome. It is showing "Undefined" when I call the function.

```js
let output = [];
let count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
    while (count <= 100) {
        if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
            output.push("FizzBuzz");
        } else if (count % 3 === 0) {
            output.push("Fizz");
        } else if (count % 5 === 0) {
            output.push("Buzz");
        } else {
            output.push(count);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

I am expecting it to output an array of numbers up to 100 but inserting "Fizz" for multiples of 3, "Buzz" for multiples of 5, and "FizzBuzz" for multiples of both 3 and 5.

Comment: You forgot to return `output` in your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want run your code without getting undefined then you can use var instead of using 'let'. Due to the variable block scope you are getting undefined.
Just replace let with var.

Then return output variable in your function body.  use console.log(your function name)

Comment: var output =[];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {


while(count<=100) {
    
    if(count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0){
        output.push("FizzBuzz");
    }else if (count % 3 === 0){
        output.push("Fizz");
    }else if (count % 5 === 0){
        output.push("Buzz");
    }else{
        output.push(count);
    }
    
count++;

    }
return output;
}

console.log(fizzBuzz());

Answer (score 2):

You have the following code

```js
let output =[]; 
let count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
    while(count<=100) {
        if(count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0){
            output.push("FizzBuzz");
        }else if (count % 3 === 0){
            output.push("Fizz");
        }else if (count % 5 === 0){
            output.push("Buzz");
        }else{
            output.push(count);
        }  
        count++;
    }
}
```

which you are executing by calling `fizzBuzz()`. You're getting `undefined` because when you call `fizzBuzz()` in the console you're seeing the return value of the execution, which in your code doesn't ever return anything, so we get undefined.

You have two options.

1. Return `output` at the end of your function, outside of the `while` loop. In this case, it'd be best to also move your `output` and `count` variables inside,  like so

```js
function fizzBuzz() {
    let output =[]; 
    let count = 1;

    while(count<=100) {
        if(count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0){
            output.push("FizzBuzz");
        }else if (count % 3 === 0){
            output.push("Fizz");
        }else if (count % 5 === 0){
            output.push("Buzz");
        }else{
            output.push(count);
        }  
        count++;
    }

    return output;
}
```

We move the `output` and `count` declarations inside so that every time we call `fizzBuzz()` we start from scratch. If we kept them outside, then if you called `fizzBuzz()` twice, we'd see the results from the first call in the results from the second call as well.

2. Your second option is to call `fizzBuzz()` with how your code currently is, and then print the value of `output`. I think you're just making a simple mistake and don't realize that your `fizzBuzz` doesn't return anything.

```js
fizzBuzz();
console.log(output);
```

or, if you're executing this in your browsers developer console then

```
fizzBuzz()
output
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return statement for the output

```js
let output =[];
let count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {


while(count<=100) {
    
    if(count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0){
        output.push("FizzBuzz");
    }else if (count % 3 === 0){
        output.push("Fizz");
    }else if (count % 5 === 0){
        output.push("Buzz");
    }else{
        output.push(count);
    }
    
count++;

    }
return output;
}

console.log(fizzBuzz());
```